# Link Buttons for Header division is misaligned with the Header bar

Tags: html, css, display

Recently, I'm learning how to develop a website for the sake of it from [Upskills](https://upskillcourses.com/). So far, I'm trying to reinforce my knowledge of HTML and CSS by starting to build the website I want. One roadblock that's frustrating me is the link buttons that are designed to fit within the header division are misaligned. Along with that, there are small spaces between each link button which is not what I want.

Here's the code for you guys to understand:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>AntsHUD</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="ndt.ttf"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <h1 class="header-logo">AntsHUD</h1>
            <a class="header-button" href="index.html">Home</a>
            <a class="header-button" href="index.html">Downloads</a>
            <a class="header-button" href="index.html">FAQ</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: arial;
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    border-bottom: 4px solid rgb(0,191,255);
}

.header-logo {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0px 14px;

    color: white;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

#header>.header-button:link, #header>.header-button:visited {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0px 16px;

    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#header>.header-button:hover, #header>.header-button:active {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0px 16px;
    background-color: rgb(0,191,255);

    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nbgasvgs/2/)

I would appreciate some help or even an explanation as to why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest you look for the concept "flexbox design". The way I choose to fix your problem is as follows:

```css
* {
 margin: 0px;
 font-family: arial;
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    border-bottom: 4px solid rgb(0,191,255);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

.header-logo {
    width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0px 14px;
   color: white;
   text-shadow: 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

a.header-button {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: auto 10px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#header>.header-button:visited,
#header>.header-button:hover, 
#header>.header-button:active {
    background-color: rgb(0,191,255);
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>AntsHUD</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="ndt.ttf"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <h1 class="header-logo">AntsHUD</h1>
            <a class="header-button" href="index.html">Home</a>
            <a class="header-button" href="index.html">Downloads</a>
            <a class="header-button" href="index.html">FAQ</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps.